# REGEX - How to filter this NGINX log message?

Tags: node.js, regex

I am sending an `access.log` message from **NGINX** to an **AWS-Lambda** (NODE) endpoint (POST).

I am receiving the follow message in the **CloudWatch**:

```
{"text":"177.41.45.264 - - [25/Sep/2020:10:20:30 -0400] 'POST /webservices/realtime/some.php HTTP/1.1' 200 35 '-' '-'"}
```

I want to filter the previous string in 4 parts:

1. 177.41.45.264
2. 25/Sep/2020:10:20:30
3. POST
4. /webservices/realtime/some.php

For now I am able to return `25/Sep/2020:10:20:30 -0400`. this is the [link](https://regex101.com/r/eng0z9/1).
Can someone give a clue in how can I achieve that?
It can be in 1 step (1 regex) or 4 steps (4 regex)

Comment: `(\d{1,3}(?:\.\d{1,3}){3})[\s-]+\[([^\]\[]+)]\s+'([A-Z]+)\s+([^\s']+)`, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/PKn1vB/1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This does it: `((?:\d{1,3}\.){3}\d{1,3}).*\[(.*)\s-\d{4}\]\s'(.*?)\s(.*?)`

See https://regex101.com/r/I8m8kD/1